# VBA Excel and Regexp

Tags: regex, excel, vba

Can you please check my code and see why it is not giving me what I want. I think it is because of the pattern but I am not so sure.

```
    Function CleanStr(strIn As String) As String
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
      .Pattern = "\([^)]*\)"
      .Global = True
      CleanStr = .Replace(strIn, vbNullString)
    End With
    End Function
```

What I want my code to do is clean the string inside a parentheses. So given something like "values(delete)" I want it to become "values()" only. But what my code does is also delete the parentheses thus making it "values".

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just replace with `()` (not with `vbNullString`).

Comment: As Wiktor said, just replace with (): `CleanStr = .Replace(strIn, "()")` or use Gurman's pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because `\(` and `\)` in your pattern matches the opening and closing parenthesis.

Use this as pattern instead:

`[^()]*(?=\))`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/we2FYT/2)

**Explanation:**

- `[^()]*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is nether a `(` nor a `)`
- `(?=\))` - Positive lookahead to make sure that the above match must be followed by a closing parenthesis `)`

Comment: @Link Please select it as the answer if it worked for you